# Javascript FadeIn code add more classes

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fadein

Im new in Javascript, Im sorry for the armature questions
i have a fadein code only for one class that works perfect, here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var fadeinbig = function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
        offset = $(window).height() / 2;
    $('.fadeinbig').each(function(){
        if (scroll-offset > $(this).position().top && $(this).hasClass('fadeinbig')) {
            $(this).removeClass('fadeinbig');
        }
    });
}
fadeinbig();
$(window).on('scroll resize', fadeinbig);
```

I would like to add some more classes like, fadeinleft, fadeinright, etc.
like this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var fadeinbig = function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
            offset = $(window).height() / 2;
        $('.fadeinbig').each(function(){
            if (scroll-offset > $(this).position().top && $(this).hasClass('fadeinbig')) {
                $(this).removeClass('fadeinbig');
            }
        });
    }
    fadeinbig();
    $(window).on('scroll resize', fadeinbig);
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var faidinbottom = function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
            offset = $(window).height() / 2;
        $('.faidinbottom').each(function(){
            if (scroll-offset > $(this).position().top && $(this).hasClass('faidinbottom')) {
                $(this).removeClass('faidinbottom');
            }
        });
    }
    faidinbottom();
    $(window).on('scroll resize', faidinbottom);
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var faidintop = function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
            offset = $(window).height() / 2;
        $('.faidintop').each(function(){
            if (scroll-offset > $(this).position().top && $(this).hasClass('faidintop')) {
                $(this).removeClass('faidintop');
            }
        });
    }
    faidintop();
    $(window).on('scroll resize', faidintop);
```

If you ask me why my code is with removeClass, not with addClass, it is becouse it is easer for me to manipulate whit my content, without changing the base css styles of my website. I just add some classes "faidintop, faidinbottom etc." to the style sheet, then to the class of a div, and the magic happens.
I will be very grateful if some one could help me whit this, or at least give me some directions, how to do it the right way.